# agregar array de objetos con la misma key dentro de otro array de objetos

Tags: javascript

Lo que necesito es unir el contenido de un array de objetos en el cual se repite el nombre de la key, dentro de otro array que ya contiene objetos. Muestro el código de ejemplo de lo que quiero decir:

```
const array1 = [
  {
    del: 1,
    age: 20,
    nombre: 'juan'
    },
  {
    del: 1,
    age: 23,
    nombre: 'pepe'
    },
  {
    del: 1,
    age: 40,
    nombre: 'maria'
    }
]

const array2 = [
  {
    tasa: 1
  },
  {
    tasa: 67 
  },
  {
    tasa: 6
  }
]
```

Necesitaría recibir esto:

```
[
  {
    del: 1,
    age: 20,
    nombre: 'juan',
    tasa: 1
    },
  {
    del: 1,
    age: 23,
    nombre: 'pepe',
    tasa: 67
    },
  {
    del: 1,
    age: 40,
    nombre: 'maria',
    tasa: 6
    }
]
```

Es mi primer post, si falta algo por añadir para que se entienda bien, por favor me lo dicen.
Gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. Si que falta algo... que nos enseñes lo que has intentado hacer para solucionar el problema. Verás, aquí no trabajamos para nadie :) Tal como se indica en las reglas de SO, debes **investigar y demostrar esfuerzo** si pretendes obtener una respuesta. Después de todo, es justo que si vamos a esforzarnos nosotros en ayudarte nos demuestres que tú mismo te has esforzado, no? Por favor, añade el código de lo que has intentado y no te ha funcionado. Para conocernos mejor, te recomiendo leer [ask] (y siempre puedes revisar [help] para + info).

Comment: Pero al menos da mas información, como sabemos qué tasa le correspode a cada uno, ¿es por el orden en el array?, que pasa si hay mas tasas que usuarios, o usuarios que tasas, trata de explicar un poco mas y mejor el caso.

Comment: Ambos tenéis razón, totalmente de acuerdo en lo que decís. Agradezco vuestros comentarios, en un futuro espero hacerlo mejor. He seguido investigando y he dado con la solución. Voy a ponerla como respuesta por si le sirve a algún compañero.

Answer (score 2):

He seguido investigando, y he dado con la solución:

```js
 const array1 = [
    {
        del: 1,
        age: 20,
        nombre: 'juan',
      },
    {
        del: 1,
        age: 23,
        nombre: 'pepe',
      },
    {
        del: 1,
        age: 40,
        nombre: 'maria',
      }
  ]
  
  const array2 = [
    {
      tasa: 1
    },
    {
         tasa: 67 
    },
    {
        tasa:6
    }
  ]
  
  let array3 = array1.map((item, i) => Object.assign({}, item, array2[i]));

  console.log(array3);
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).